# Move Laravel with() Json array to parent Json array

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I am using this code to obtain data.

```
$user = User::where('active', 1)->with(['spots:spot_name,spot_uid'])->get();
```

This is working great!  It gets the relationship and outputs the data.

However the data looks like this.

```
user_uid: 5
spots: {spot_name: 'backend'}
description: "Test user works in helpdesk"
department: "9"
```

It is showing all the data I need, but I would like for the **spot_name** to not be in its own child json array and just have the **spot_name** be **spots**. Like this:

```
spots: "backend"
```

I know this is because it obtains the 2 columns and then I have one hidden.

Is this not possible, or am I just going about it the wrong way?  Any information would be great.

Comment: What if `spots` returns two records, like `spots: [{spot_name: 'front_end'}, {spot_name: 'backend'}]`? Or is `spots` a `hasOne()` or `belongsTo()` relationship? If so, it's named poorly; should be `spot`. Also, `$user` is a bad variable name for `->get()`, which returns _multiple_ `User` instances; consider renaming to `$users`.

Comment: Sorry these names have been cut and changed for posting as they were fairly long.  However, it is named spots because in that example the table is spots but returns based on a spot_uid.  So, it can only return one.  

Your complaint of the json showing spots is what I want to remove.  That is the problem.  I also want to remove the name spots from the outgoing json. Just leaving that 1 spot_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it

```
User::where('active', 1)->withCount(['spots as spot_name' => function ($q) {
                $q->select('spot_name');
            }]);
```

output

```
 {
    ...
    spot_name: 'backend'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format output with collections:

```php
$user->map(function ($x) {
  $arr = $x->toArray();
  $arr['spots'] = $arr['spots'][0]['spot_name'];
  return $arr;
});
```

And then out this user.

Comment: That code won't work. What is `$user` in the closure?

Comment: My bad. Fixed @miken32

Comment: Thanks!  I think this should also work!